# div versus svg positioning

Tags: html, dom, svg

I'm struggling to understand why the content in a div is appearing ON TOP of content in an svg, even though the svg is added to the page after the div.

I've just read through a bunch of similar posts but wasn't able to find something applying to my problem, so I'm really hoping someone notices something wrong with the code below.  To clarify, the 3 rect are appearing on top of the 3 circles - I've experimented using the z-index property on the div but it has no effect.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class = "scrollMenu" style="position:absolute; left:0%; top:10%;">
            <svg>
                <rect>
                <rect>
                <rect>
            </svg>
        </div>

        <svg>
            <g>
                <circle>
                <circle>
                <circle>
            </g>
        </svg>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: Because `position:absolute;`.

Comment: Thanks Alexander - but what does position have to be to enable this not to happen?  It won't work with fixed either right?  How can I anchor a div to a certain position but also avoid it appearing on top of elements further down the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `div` has positioning and positioned elements stack above non-positioned ones.

To resolve this, you can add `position: relative` to your `svg` element.

#### Example:

```css
svg {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
svg.red {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
svg.blue {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollMenu" style="position:absolute; left:0%; top:10%;">
    <svg class="blue">
        <rect />
        <rect />
        <rect />
    </svg>
</div>

<svg class="red">
    <g>
        <circle />
        <circle />
        <circle />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks very much - and now the z-index works beautifully on the div.